# Factorials...How do they do it?

Tags: factorial

So I've been recently arguing with my teacher about factorials. My teacher says that factorials can only be calculated for integers, because the definition of factorials is as follows:

> the product of an integer and all the integers below it

But I've seen many different calculators where you can find the factorials of real numbers, like $5!$, $1.1!$, $-5.7!$, $\sqrt 2!$ or $(\tan 85)!$ and so on...

How do calculators do this? What formula do they use? It's obviously not $(n) \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times 1$ where $n$ is some integer. (In this case it's any real number)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: "The gamma function is defined for all complex numbers except the negative integers and zero" 
But I can take factorials of negitive numbers and zeros too!

Comment: @CaptCoonoor It is the "nice" extension of the factorial on the nonnegative integers. It turns out there is not such a "nice" extension which also goes to the negative integers.

Comment: Oh thanks btw, I need to learn integrals first to learn this function till now we have been only taught differential calculus

Comment: @CaptCoonoor: $\Gamma(0)=(-1)!\neq0!=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The calculator is using the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), that satisfies for natural numbers $n$
$$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$$
and it is given by
$$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
However, note that when you say $-5.7!$, that means $-(5.7!),$ not $(-5.7)!$.

Comment: Wait a second, does (-5.7)! and -(5.7)! makes any difference?

Comment: Of course. The first one would be $\Gamma(-5.7+1)$, and the second would be $-\Gamma(5.7+1)$. Just like if $f(x) = x^2$ then $f(-2) = 4$, but $-f(2) = -4.$